# What's the difference between AdBlock and AdBlock Plus

Tags: advertisements

I think this is the correct place to post this. I'm trying to determine what the difference is between Adblock and AdBlock Plus? Either of them don't seem to work with the latest version of Safari.

Comment: Questions about browser add-ons are considered off-topic here.  This question should be migrated over to SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://www.freewaregenius.com/adblock-v-adblock-plus-two-chrome-extensions-compared/) and [here.](http://jackworld.xyz/adblock-vs-adblock-plus/)

Here's a comparison.
[image]

1. Adblock and Adblock Plus have no connection what so ever.
2. Adblock Plus is the original extension created by Wladimir Palant for Firefox.
3. Adblock came into picture as a popular extension with similar capacities for Chrome.

> "AdBlock is not to be confused with Adblock Plus. The creator of AdBlock claims to have been inspired by the AdBlock Plus extension for Firefox, but otherwise the two efforts are unrelated."

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus)

> "ABP, a forked version of an earlier, discontinued extension called
>   Adblock, allows users to prevent page elements, such as
>   advertisements, from being downloaded and displayed...Michael McDonald
>   of Provo, Utah, created Adblock Plus 0.5 that improved on the original
>   AdBlock by incorporating the following features:

```
whitelisting
support for blocking background images
subscription to filters with a fixed address and automatic updates
the ability to hide HTML elements, allowing a greater range of images to be blocked
the ability to hide ads on a per-site basis, instead of globally
memory leak fixes
improvements to the user interface
```

McDonald discontinued development and transferred the name to Wladimir Palant, who released Adblock Plus 0.6 with a rewritten codebase in January 2006. PC World chose Adblock Plus as one of the 100 best products of 2007."

**As for why it doesn't work on the latest version of Safari**, you need to provide more information. Does it successfully install? Do you subscribe to the lists for blocking? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more information about the difference between the two: http://readwrite.com/2014/08/01/adblock-plus-switch-adblock

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.